# How to get live update when working with Jquery Editable plugin and knockout js used together to edit in place

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

often i use jquery in web application. but nowadays knockout js and angular js is using many people for declarative data binding. i roughly read knockout js documentation from there web site.

i got a code which display data in tabular fashion for shopping cart system and i checked it is working but i saw one lack in code that when i change price or quantity then instantly amount is not changing but all properties are observable. later i could guess why amount is not changing instantly when price or Qty is changing because jquery editable plugin dynamically place a textbox which is not bound to any observable property.

so anyone could tell me how to dynamically add or place knockout js bind attribute to dynamically generate textbox for in-place edit ?

here is jsfiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/nzogas5z/`

### and full code

```
<table id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:150px">Product</th>
        <th>Price ($)</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Amount ($)</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody data-bind='template: {name: "orderTemplate", foreach: orders}'></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="orderTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: product"></td>
        <td class="editable number" data-bind="dataCell: price, valueUpdate: 'keypress'" ></td>
        <td class="editable number"data-bind="dataCell: quantity"></td>
        <td class="number" data-bind="text: amount"></td>
    </tr>
</script>

$(function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.dataCell = {

        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                setTimeout(function() { value($(element).text()); }, 0);
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                existing = $(element).text();

            if (value != existing) {
                $(element).text(value);    
            }
        }

    };

    var order = function (product, price, quantity) {
        this.product = product;
        this.price = ko.observable(price);
        this.quantity = ko.observable(quantity);
        this.amount = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            return this.price() * this.quantity();
        }, this);
    }

    var ordersModel = function () {
        this.orders = ko.observableArray([]);
    }


    var viewModel = new ordersModel();
    viewModel.orders = ko.observableArray([
            new order("Gala Apple", 0.79, 150),
            new order("Naval Orange", 0.29, 500)
        ]);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    //alert(viewModel.orders.length());

    $('.editable').editable({ onEdit: edit, onSubmit: submit, onCancel: cancel });

    $(".editable").change();
});

function edit(content) {
    $(this).addClass("editing");
    $(this).children('input').get(0).select();
}

function submit(content) {
    $(this).removeClass("editing");
    $(this).change();
}

function cancel(content) {
    $(this).removeClass("editing");
}
```

i want when i change price or Qty then amount fields should recalculate instantly. guide me what to achieve. thanks

Comment: @JamesThorpe Not very clear....could not visualize what i need to change in code. good hints please.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry - I wasn't entirely clear on what your problem is.  I see now that your code works, it's just you want the live updates when in the editing box.  My comment didn't really address that.  Which editable plugin are you using - does it have events for onchange/keydown etc?

Comment: yes i want the live updates when typing text in the editing box.....how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get live updates, you need the `textInput` binding from Knockout 3.3 (or you'd have to roll your own). I've made [a modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opd0x2vm/5/) that uses Knockout to simulate the jquery-editable behavior via a custom binding handler that uses a span (with `text` binding behavior) and an input (with `textInput` binding behavior).

I got rid of the templating and built the table body with an ordinary foreach binding. I chose to do the showing and hiding with CSS and an `editing` class, but you could do explicit calls to `show` and `hide` if you prefer.

```
<tbody data-bind='foreach: orders'>
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: product"></td>
        <td class="number editable" data-bind="dataCell:price"></td>
        <td class="number editable" data-bind="dataCell:quantity"></td>
        <td class="number" data-bind="text: amount"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

All the jQuery stuff is handled by a custom bindingHandler.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dataCell = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        var span = $('<span>').appendTo($(element))[0];
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.init(span, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context);
        var input = $('<input>').appendTo($(element))[0];
        ko.bindingHandlers.textInput.init(input, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context);
        $(element).click(function () {
            $(element).addClass('editing');
            $(input).focus().select();
        });
        $(input).blur(function () {
            $(element).removeClass('editing');
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var span = $(element).children('span')[0];
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(span, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
    }
};
```

The binding handler does these things:

1. Creates a span and an input inside the element with the binding (the td, in our example)
2. Calls the `init` function for the standard `text` binding on the span
3. Calls the `init` function for the standard `textInput` binding on the input
4. Attaches `click` trigger to the bound element (the td) to go into editing mode (show input, hide span)
5. Attaches `blur` trigger to the input element to end editing mode (show span, hide input)
6. In the `update` section, calls the standard `update` binding on the input

Comment: thanks a lot for your code. u may notice that i have good reputation for stackoverflow but i am not very advanced developer but achieve many point because i often post very realistic question. anyway your code is working but very honestly i just do not understand your custom binding logic for `dataCell `. would you mind to explain which line put a textbox for in-place edit. if possible please explain custom binding each line. looking for your co-operation. thanks

Comment: I've added a basic explanation to my answer. The lines in the init section beginning with var are the ones that create the span and input elements. The lines that begin with ko call the standard handler functions on those elements. The lines that begin with $ create the triggers.